# How to view and edit windows registry from a remote linux machine?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-registry

On the windows-linux interoperability front we have [Samba](http://samba.org/) for file/print sharing (SMB/CIFS), [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) for terminal services (RDP).  Is there any linux tool available that will allow you to view and edit the registry of a remote windows machine (ie. not a dual-boot situation where your trying to hack the files from the windows partition while running linux)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is so trivial to do over a remote desktop or vnc connection that there's little pressure for such a tool. It seems `regedit` actually runs under `wine`, and can be directed to open a network registry. The same can be said of [`reglite`](http://www.resplendence.com/reglite).

Comment: +1 I can confirm it certainly does work under Wine. I recently had a need to do exactly that and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm not seeing any remote option in the wine version of regedit

Answer (score -2):

Offline, you can edit a Windows Registry from Linux using the [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/), although if you are physically booting up the Windows box from a Linux CD, you might as well just boot into Windows and use the native tools.  Remotely, your best bet would probably be to just use rdesktop to log into the computer remotely, and then use regedit to edit the registry.

Comment: While true, the question asks about a remote computer.